# how to read specific columns spaced by tab space from a text file in python

Tags: python

How to read using python from a text file has float values columns spaced by tab space as the following:

```
1.0    11.0   23.0
2.0    22.0   45.0
3.0    33.0   456.0
4.0    44.0   3456.0
5.0    55.0   33212.0
```

I want to read the specific column, say column 1, 2 or 3.
Could any one give me a corresponding python code?

Comment: `[line.split()[your_column-1] for line in open('your_file')]`

Comment: I wrote this code as explained, but it not working:

lines=text_file.read()
result=[]
for x in lines:
    result.append(x.split()[0]) #2nd column
print(result)
text_file.close()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `split` for spliting the string and `strip` for removing whitespaces

```
with open(filename,'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        a,b,c = [float(x.strip()) for x in line.split()]
```

Comment: Ok, it working with me. But when the data inside the text file is changed to be like below, the code gives the following error:

['f4:d9:fb:d6:b4:6f  \t-80\t17\t72.6471\n', '\n', 'f4:d9:fb:cf:9b:e0  \t-91\t17\t72.6471\n', '\n', 'f4:d9:fb:cf:fb:ef  \t-69\t17\t72.6471\n'].
The error: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 0)

Comment: I found that the problem is because found the ('\n') after the end of each line, how I can remove it from the list?

Comment: `strip()` will remove the new `\n`

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the file, `.strip` the trailing `\n` and then split on each line with `.split('\n')`. You can then iterate through each row in a comprehension using the same `.split` method on each line to get the floats.

So, we can create the data structure with:

```
x = [r.split() for r in open('file.txt').read().strip().split('\n')]
```

but this does not convert the strings to floats, for that we need to use a nested comprehension:

```
x = [[float(c) for c in r.split()] \
     for r in open('file.txt').read().strip().split('\n')]
```

Now if we want the second element on the third row, we can just call:

```
x[2][1]
```

which gives us `33.0` as a float.

Comment: Not sure about using `open()` within the list comprehension. Isn't it safer to use a `with` statement? +1 nevertheless

Comment: @Igid All a `with` statement does is close the file even when there is an error. Yes, Ideally you would use one but for the sake of the neatness of the answer I left it out.

Answer (score 1):

Using pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep="\t")
```